# Facebook feed post's link opens on the current browser window

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to post a link using Android SDK.

Clicking my post anchor doesn't open a new browser window, it is using the current tab (the facebook profile/news feed) instead. This results in the user is loosing his/her faecbook browser tab.

This doesn't seem to me like the intended behavior. Other applications (youtube, NewYorkTimes) do open up a new tab. Maybe it is somehow related, that both my app's **site url** and **canvas url** are set to the same URL that the feed's link attribute points to.

Checking the anchor's source, I see that it lacks `target='_blank'` HTML attribute (youtube video posts do have that attribute).

### Edit:

Maybe I wasn't making myself clear...
The issue here is not at the stage of posting the feed to the user's wall. The issue only occurs after a successful post using the **feed dialog**, when clicking that post (either the post's attached picture or the link) on the user's wall. When doing so, you are being redirected  to the link's address (out of facebook) on your current browser tab.

### Edit 2:

I am using someone else's code, it is a Cordova (Phonegap) facebook plugin.

@Malione, The full code I am using can be found under https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-facebook-connect.

I have copy-pasted one function that may be the relevant function 
( located under `src\com\facebook\android\Facebook.java`), and added 2 log lines that might also be helpful:

```
    /**
 * Cordova interface to display a dialog
 */
public PluginResult dialog(final JSONArray args, final String callbackId) throws JSONException, FileNotFoundException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    Log.d(CLASS, "dialog() :" + args.toString());
    JSONObject params = args.getJSONObject(0);
    PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);

    final String method = params.has("method") ? params.getString("method") : "feed";
    JSONObject optionsObject = (JSONObject)params.get("params");
    final Bundle options = new Bundle();
    Iterator<?> keys = optionsObject.keys();
    while( keys.hasNext() ){
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        options.putString(key, optionsObject.getString(key));
        //if(optionsObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject)
    }

    final FacebookConnect me = this;
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Log.d("Roei ------->>>>>>>Dialog options:", options.toString());
            Log.d("Roei ------->>>>>>>Dialog context:", me.cordova.getContext().toString() );
            me.getFacebook().dialog(me.cordova.getContext(), method, options, new RegularDialogListener(me, callbackId));
        };
    };
    pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
    this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);

    return pluginResult;
}
```

And this is the log file's output:

```
08-28 20:21:18.015: D/CordovaLog(25340): picture: https://surf-space.com/wp-content/uploads/spots/user_reports/default/surf-report.jpg
08-28 20:21:18.015: D/CordovaLog(25340): : Line 1172087949 : picture: https://surf-space.com/wp-content/uploads/spots/user_reports/default/surf-report.jpg
08-28 20:21:18.015: I/Web Console(25340): picture: https://surf-space.com/wp-content/uploads/spots/user_reports/default/surf-report.jpg at :1172087949
08-28 20:21:18.025: D/dalvikvm(25340): GC_CONCURRENT freed 395K, 49% free 3328K/6471K, external 598K/1065K, paused 6ms+3ms
08-28 20:21:18.035: D/FacebookConnect(25340): dialog() :[{"method":"feed","params":{"picture":"https:\/\/surf-space.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/spots\/user_reports\/default\/surf-report.jpg",
"method":"feed","description":"Wave height: 1.3 Meters<center \/>Surf conditions: Fine<center \/>","link":"https:\/\/surf-space.com\/spots\/israel\/","name":"Roei Bahumi posted a surf report for: Neurim, Netanya"}}]
08-28 20:21:18.035: D/Roei ------->>>>>>>Dialog options:(25340): Bundle[{picture=https://surf-space.com/wp-content/uploads/spots/user_reports/default/surf-report.jpg, method=feed, description=Wave height: 1.3 
Meters<center />Surf conditions: Fine<center />, name=Roei Bahumi posted a surf report for: Neurim, Netanya, link=https://surf-space.com/spots/israel/}]
08-28 20:21:18.035: D/DroidGap(25340): This will be deprecated December 2012
08-28 20:21:18.035: D/Roei ------->>>>>>>Dialog context:(25340): com.surf_space.surf_space4.MainActivity@405eb938
08-28 20:21:18.035: D/DroidGap(25340): This will be deprecated December 2012
08-28 20:21:19.897: W/InputManagerService(171): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40a82a20
08-28 20:21:28.125: D/FacebookConnect(25340): RegularDialogListener::onComplete() Bundle[{post_id=839443974_490613954283080}]
08-28 20:21:28.155: D/CordovaLog(25340): FacebookConnect.dialog:{"post_id":"839443974_490613954283080"}
08-28 20:21:28.155: D/CordovaLog(25340): : Line 1172088957 : FacebookConnect.dialog:{"post_id":"839443974_490613954283080"}
08-28 20:21:28.155: I/Web Console(25340): FacebookConnect.dialog:{"post_id":"839443974_490613954283080"} at :1172088957
```

Is this the part of the code you were talking about? Do you see something missing in the data sent to facebook?

If not, can you please direct me to a Facebook Android SDK documentation page, that explain how to set `target='_blank'`, or even show an example request that does so, I will be grateful (and will also know what to look for in the code).

Comment: are you Creating an app?

Comment: Yes, I am creating an app. One of this apps functionalities is posting to a user wall using the 'feed' method. The problem is, as I previously mentioned, that the anchor (<a> HTML tag) on the user's wall doesn't contain the `target='_blank'` attribute.

Comment: did you try adding the `target='_blank'` attribute to the HTML in your Code?

Comment: What do you mean?

my code only send the post using the feed dialog, similar to this  [javascript SDK example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/).

So the link is a STRING attribute of a javascript object:
`link:'http://example.com'`

There is no anchor element here to add the `target='_blank'`.

The problematic post is on the user's facebook wall, where this `target='_blank'` is missing.

Comment: if you look [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)  under Display Modes it gives an option for SmartPhones (touch) and popups. if you are using that specific SDK

Comment: Hi @Malione, thanks for trying to help out here. Please check my 'EDIT' section on my original post.

Comment: it still sounds like you need to mess around with the Code, there should be some point in the code where it creates the links to post on Facebook, this is where you add `target = '_blank'` the line of code ` link:'http://httpexample.com'` is used by another class to create a link, that is where you need to change the code, in that other class that builds the `HTML`

Comment: is the **Feed Dialog** your Code or someone else's code? either way you should provide the code that you have so we can see what is going on

Comment: Hi @Malioneת
Did you see my "Edit 2" update? Do you have any idea what causing this issue?